# Embedded ARM and C runtime

Tags: c, linker, arm, bare-metal

I'm experimenting with bare metal programming on an ARM1176JZ-F processor (RPi B+), and trying to understand the role of the C runtime at the same time.

I am using the arm-none-eabi-gcc tool chain for cross compilation of my basic kernel (which boils down to just moving about a few bits in and out of registers and memory) written in C, using the following flags:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv6zk -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -nostartfiles foo.c
```

I am having some trouble with automatic variables in my code, and need some guidance!

Firstly, I am not sure of the relationship between the runtime library and the "startup" routines, are these one and the same, with "-nostartfiles" effectively not linking the runtime, or are these routines only one part of the job of the runtime library?

Secondly, I am not sure how the runtime relates to automatic variables, which I have noticed, although not causing a compilation error, aren't working!

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Edit: see code snippet below. The program does not seem to work (but will compile fine) if the |gpioBase| and |timer| variables are declared within the main function block.

```
/*
* armc1.c
*
* flash PWR/ACT LEDs on RPi B+
*
**/

#include <stdint.h>

//variables declared outside function block, no runtime support = no automatic variables!
volatile uint32_t* gpioBase; //BCM2835 gpio base
volatile uint32_t time; //timer

int main(void) {
  gpioBase = (uint32_t*)(0x20200000UL); //BCM2835 gpio physical address
  //set outputs
  gpioBase[3] = (1<<15); //GPFSEL3 @ 0x2020000C = 0b0..001..0, GPIO35 as output
  gpioBase[4] = (1<<21); //GPFSEL4 @ 0x20200010 = 0b0..001..0, GPIO47 as output
  //infinite loop, no OS
  while(1) {
    gpioBase[8] = (1<<3); //GPSET1-SET35 @ 0x20200020 = 1, GPIO35 on
    gpioBase[8] = (1<<15); //GPSET1-SET47 @ 0x20200020 = 1, GPIO47 on
    for(time = 0;time < 500000;time++); //waste time
    gpioBase[11] = (1<<3); //GPCLR1-CLR35 @ 0x2020002C = 1, GPIO35 off
    gpioBase[11] = (1<<15); //GPCLR1-CLR47 @ 0x2020002C = 1, GPIO47 off
    for(time = 0;time < 500000;time++); //waste time
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "automatic variables are not working"? How do you know they aren't? What automatic variables? Do you have a minimal code example?

Comment: I am guessing you haven't provided any startup code, which, among some other stuff, is defining the stack location and size. Automatic variables are allocated on the stack, so it could be the reason.

Comment: If you just use `_start:` in your code, you must clear `.bss` (global zero vars) and setup space for a stack.  Typcially, you control the address layout via a linker script.  `_start()` should be in assembler as it does not need a stack nor `.bss` if coded properly.  It is possible to write in 'C', but it will be non-standard and it is probably clearer in assembler unless you have no clue about assembler; but then you will probably fail to get the 'C' to work.

Comment: Post edited to include sample code. I'm trying to scaffold upwards from assembly to C. I do broadly understand ARM assembly, but am trying to do as much as possible without resorting to it directly! I am mostly focussed on trying to understand the C runtime, could you be a bit clearer as to what you mean by "startup code " and the "_start:" label and what it does?

Comment: In C local variables are put on the stack so if you do not set the stackpointer up the code can't create variables at runtime. in contrast if you put them before main they are compiled into the bootimage and as a result of this loaded by the bootloader. The start label is simply where the code starts that the bootloader puts into mem.

Comment: if you do bare metal programming in C you won't come around a tiny little bit of assembler code. (set up stackpointer)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's replies!

As indicated by artless noise & scaletos, I did indeed need to do a bit of assembly to get the code working. All that was needed was a small bit of entry point magic setting up the stack and a little bit of help from a linker script to clear the .bss section.